# Puppet generates errors every time a module changes

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I have a trivial puppet 2.7.18 installation as follows:

```
=== manifests/site.pp ===
node build-1 {
  include mod1
  include mod2
  include mod3
}

=== modules/mod1/manifests/init.pp ===
import "*"

=== modules/mod1/manifests/mod1.pp ===
class mod1 {
  file { "/tmp/mod1.file": ensure => present }
}

=== modules/mod2/manifests/init.pp ===
import "*"

=== modules/mod2/manifests/mod2.pp ===
class mod2 {
  file { "/tmp/mod2.file": ensure => present }
}

=== modules/mod3/manifests/init.pp ===
import "*"

=== modules/mod3/manifests/mod3.pp ===
class mod3 {
  file { "/tmp/mod3.file": ensure => present }
}
```

When I try to run puppet agent on the build-1 host, I get the following message:

```
: 0 build-1; sudo puppet agent --noop --test
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find class mod1 for build-1 at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:2 on node build-1
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

If I run it again, I get the same message, but for class mod2. Running it a third time gives me the message for class mod3. Finally, running it a fourth time works. But, if I do nothing more than touch one of the module files (e.g., mod1.pp), then I have to go through the whole thing again; running puppet agent until every module recompiles properly. This is obviously not sustainable.

Some other things I noticed:

1. This seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289988/puppet-could-not-find-class-hiccups-often-once-after-manifest-module-change, except that one appears to be for version 3.0 and the bug ticket it refers to specifically says that it doesn't affect 2.7. In any case, switching to a passenger setup didn't help.
2. If I change the module layout to just put the whole module definition into init.pp instead of importing the real module definition, I don't get the problem. But that's not going to scale well for complicated modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't have the definition of the main class in the `init.pp` file?

My understanding of the class discovery is rudimentary, but the file `modules/mod1/mod1.pp` would be automatically checked for the `mod1::mod1` class, not the `mod1` class.

As far as I'm aware, the `mod1` class should always be defined in `init.pp`, but that doesn't mean your entire module's config has to be in there - sub-classes are helpful!

The module design that I believe is recommended these days is along these lines:

`mod1/init.pp`:

```
class mod1 {
  include mod1::install
  include mod1::config
  include mod1::service
}
```

`mod1/install.pp`:

```
class mod1::install {
  package { "somepackage":
    ensure => installed,
  }
}
```

`mod1/config.pp`:

```
class mod1::config {
  file { "/etc/someapp.conf":
    content => "foo",
    require => Class["mod1::install"],
    notify  => Class["mod1::service"],
  }
}
```

`mod1/service.pp`:

```
class mod1::service {
  service { "someapp":
    ensure => running,
  }
}
```

**Edit:** further, you shouldn't be using `import` inside of modules:

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_import.html

> The behavior of import within autoloaded manifests is undefined, and may vary randomly between minor versions of Puppet. You should never place import statements in modules; they should only exist in site.pp.

Comment: Module discovery is pretty straightforward.  If you use `class { 'mod1': }` (or `include mod1`), Puppet will look for `mod1/manifests/init.pp` in its $modulepath.  If you use `class { 'mod1::classa': }`, Puppet will look for `mod1/manifests/classa.pp`.  The problem here is almost certainly because of the `import` keyword, which should really be avoided these days.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely the import that is causing this. I was migrating from an old puppet 0.24 installation that used imports everywhere. I did look for a migration guide before starting on this, but there doesn't appear to be one on the puppet site.